# How to add existing typescript file as link in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, typescript

How to add an existing typescript file as link in visual studio?

Comment: Link to the output JS instead?

Comment: adding the .js file only can cause typescript errors because the compiler does not know the typescript-defined interfaces. they aren't in the .js file.

Answer (score 0):

The typescript compiler generates a .js file. You have to add the generated .js and not the .ts file.
[Here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial) you can see how this works.

Answer (score 0):

If I am sharing a TypeScript library across multiple projects, I package it. You can use whatever packaging technology you are using to share other components. I have used NuGet and NPM successfully for this.

You can package the TypeScript file, or the pairing of the generated JavaScript file and accompanying `.d.ts` type definition (which can be auto-generated by the TypeScript compiler). The latter is the recommended packaging mechanism, though you can exercise your judgement if you are dealing with internal packages.

Not only does this solve the problem of file resolution (you will have trouble with linked files in Visual Studio) - it will come with all the usual benefits of package management.